# display date-time details on an image in codenameone

Tags: image, codenameone

I'm working on a feature in codenameone application, wherein user can capture a photo and save/display it with date,time details on it. Can these details be stored as part of the image? how can I display these details on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a mutable image and draw the original image on it then draw the date and time/save it.

```
Image img = Image.create(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(original, 0, 0);
g.setColor(0xffffff);
g.setFont(myFont);
g.drawString(0, 0, todaysDateAndTime);
ImageIO io = ImageIO.getInstance();
io.save(....);
```

I did the code above from my head so it might have some issues and didn't implement the call to save but the basics should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Great, FYI when an answer works you should generally upvote and check the checkbox next to the answer to get & give points